# Aren't there any better ways of displaying an object other than using hierarchy?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a class hierarchy as such:

```
        +-- VirtualNode
        |
INode --+                  +-- SiteNode
        |                  |
        +-- AbstractNode --+
                           |
                           +-- SiteSubNode
```

And a corresponding `NodeCollection` class that is build on `INode`. In order to display a `NodeCollection` I need to know the final type of each member. So I need a function like this

```
foreach (INode n in myNodeCollection)
{
    switch(n.GetType())
    {
        case(typeof(SiteNode)):
        // Display n as SiteNode
    }
}
```

Now, this is really not an object oriented way of doing it. **Are there any patterns or recommended ways of doing the same thing, in your opinion?**

**EDIT**
I already thought of adding a `Display` or `Render` method to the INode interface. That has the side effect of coupling the view to the model, which I would really like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after is the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), I think.

Comment: Perhaps. I've only ever used the traditional visitor pattern. I'll certainly spend time looking into this though.

Answer (score 1):

[Polymorphism:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming)

When ever you have a select statement using the type of an object, it is a prime candidate for refactoring to polymorphism.

Check out the book [Refactoring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672) by Martin Fowler:

"One of the most obvious symptoms of object-oriented code is its comparative lack of switch (or
case) statements. The problem with switch statements is essentially that of duplication. Often you
find the same switch statement scattered about a program in different places. If you add a new
clause to the switch, you have to find all these switch, statements and change them. The objectoriented
notion of polymorphism gives you an elegant way to deal with this problem.

Most times you see a switch statement you should consider polymorphism. The issue is where
the polymorphism should occur. Often the switch statement switches on a type code. You want
the method or class that hosts the type code value. So use Extract Method to extract the switch
statement and then Move Method to get it onto the class where the polymorphism is needed. At
that point you have to decide whether to Replace Type Code with Subclasses or Replace
Type Code with State/Strategy. When you have set up the inheritance structure, you can use
Replace Conditional with Polymorphism."

Here is one approach to using polymorphism in your situation:

1. Define an abstract method in
   AbstractNode named something like
   Display().
2. Then actually implement Display() in
   each of the SiteNode and SiteSubNode
   classes.
3. Then, when you need to display these
   nodes, you could simply iterate
   through a collection containing
   items of type AbstractNode and call
   Display() for each.
4. The call to Display() will
   automatically resolve to the actual
   concrete implementation for the real
   type of that item.
5. Note: You could also move the
   Display() method from AbstractNode
   to the INode interface if
   VirtualNode is to be displayed.

Comment: I don't want to do that because it would couple the view to the model!

Comment: How so?  Which classes in your example are view and which are model?  
You do realise that simply by using inheritence you are automatically coupling the child to the parent class?  Polymorphism or not.

Comment: Like I said,use the Visitor pattern. Define an INodeVisitor interface and create a NodeDisplayer class that implements that interface. Use the visitor pattern to decouple the node hierarchy from the classes that refer to the nodes.

Comment: Andrew, for simplicity having a Display() method in each class is still perfectly viable approach.  Display() could still quite happily delegate to some other UI oriented object. The Visitor pattern is overkill in simpler situations.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the INode interface - add a virtual method that returns the "view" and override it in the inherited classes.

If you can't change the base interface - implement extension methods for each of the classes and have them return the "view" of for each particular class.